# How to redirect X output to file?

Tags: server, xorg, video, xserver, x11-forwarding

I know with linux the server X that manage Ui is a protocol with client server. So the app that use UI didn't directly render thing.

It transmit to server X that render it with hardware.

So the server X can be on a remote machine.

I know that their is some virtual server X. Like Xvfb

I have a ubuntu server and want to launch some graphical program. But i don't want to get the output on my local computer i want it to be stored in a file.(video file) on the server computer

The goal is to make a site. And the user param a programm and launch. The server launch it and record GUI to file. And when over the user receive a link to download the video result.

Is their anyway to directly redirect X to a file?